# On Error Goto Msg Doesn't work properly

Tags: vba, excel

Good day to all!

I'm currently writing a code that transposes some data. My current issue with the code is that the "ErrMsg" pops up even when there is no error. If I were to put "Exit Sub" after "On Error GoTo ErrMsg", the whole module fails to continue and I am also unable to call the next module too. Hope someone can help me out here!

The code I have below runs fine but it shows the MsgBox even though there is no error.

```
Sub Five_Transpose()

Dim LPID As Range
Dim InvestorName As Range
Dim DataTableX As ListObject
Dim Rng As Range
Dim rngB As Range

    With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .DisplayAlerts = False
    End With

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Funds Table"

    Sheets("Filtered Data").Copy After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "X"

    On Error GoTo ErrMsg

    With Sheets("X")
    Set DataTableX = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(1)
    DataTableX.Name = "DataTableX"
    .Range("DataTableX[#All]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=2, Header:=xlYes
    .Range(Range("A1"), Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Funds Table").Range("B4")
    .Range(Range("B1"), Range("B1").End(xlDown)).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Funds Table").Range("A4")
    .Range("DataTableX[#All]").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=4, Header:=xlYes
    Set LPID = .Cells.Range(Range("C1"), Range("C1").End(xlDown))
    Set InvestorName = .Cells.Range(Range("D1"), Range("D1").End(xlDown))
    End With

    LPID.Copy
    Sheets("Funds Table").Range("B2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True
    InvestorName.Copy
    Sheets("Funds Table").Range("B1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=True

    Sheets("Funds Table").Select
    Set Rng = Range(Range("B1:B3"), Range("B1:B3").End(xlToRight))
    Set rngB = Range(Range("B5"), Range("B5").End(xlDown))

    With Rng.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ThemeColor = 6
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    With rngB.Borders
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ThemeColor = 6
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    With Range("B3")
    .Font.Bold = "True"
    .Value = "Funds with IRR"
    .Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
    .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent2
    End With

    Sheets("X").Delete

    With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .DisplayAlerts = True
    End With

ErrMsg:
MsgBox ("There are no funds that are within 3 Quarters from now"), , "Message Box:"

Call Six_Continue

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you print out the `Err.Number`? It could be `0`, where there's actually no error, but it will still prompt the `msgbox`

Comment: Just put `Exit Sub` before `ErrMsg:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format your code like this:

```
Sub Five_Transpose()

...code...

On Error GoTo ErrMsg

...code...

ExitPoint:
   Call Six_Continue
   'run any cleanup, like turning _
   'screenupdating back on, etc.
Exit Sub

ErrMsg:
   MsgBox "There are no funds that " & _
       "are within 3 Quarters from now", _
       , "Message Box"
   Resume ExitPoint

End Sub
```

Many consider the method of using both an exit point as well as an error handler to be a best practice. While not *always* appropriate, it is much of the time.

By setting procedures up this way you can still do all of your code cleanup on exit (**crucial** if you're turning switches off and on, because it ensures that they are returned to the desired state), you can call your sub (just make sure that it won't error out if this procedure errors out and it was reliant on something in this procedure), and you can provide the user with an error message on failure while still elegantly exciting the sub.

It works properly because if the code succeeds, it just continues down through the `ExitPoint` line and then exits. If it fails, it immediately jumps to the error handler which then sends it to the `ExitPoint`.

Comment: If the code runs into an error, the msgbox appears but after I click okay the whole excel sheet stops responding. Any possible reason for this?

If I remove "Resume ExitPoint" it works, will there be any possible implication for this?

Comment: What does your `Six_Continue` sub/function do?

Answer (score 0):

> To prevent error-handling code from running when no error has
>   occurred, place an Exit Sub, Exit Function, or Exit Property statement
>   immediately before the error-handling routine, as in the following
>   fragment:
>
> ```
> Sub InitializeMatrix(Var1, Var2, Var3, Var4)
>    On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
>    . . .
>    Exit Sub
> ErrorHandler:
>    . . .
>    Resume Next
> End Sub
> ```

From **Help** https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa266173(v=vs.60).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is an example how you can use Error-handling.  I recommend you to read more about Error Handling here: (http://www.cpearson.com/excel/errorhandling.htm)

```
sub test()

'define your variables

On Error GoTo errHandler:

'Some codes

errHandler:
 If Err.Number = -2147352567 Then
    MsgBox "Sorry, Something Went Wrong!"
    Exit Sub
 ElseIf Err.Number = 0 Then
    'no error no Action needed.
 Else
    MsgBox "An Error Occur!!" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
    "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & _
    "Error Description: " & Err.Description
    Exit Sub
 End If

End Ub
```